# Ajax in textfield adding extra div in markup

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I have created a form using a custom module. I am working on `ajax` functionality and updating `markup` when user enter text in `textfield` of the form.

Creating form in module

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form().
 */            

  $form['name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#description' => 'Enter your name',
    '#title' => 'Name',
    '#size' => 50,
    '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => 'custom_print_ajax_name_callback',
        'wrapper' => 'custom-print-name',
        'method' => 'replace',
  ),
  );   

  $form['name_msg'] = array(
    '#type' => 'item',
    '#markup' => (!empty($form_state['input']['name']) ? $form_state['input']['name'] : ''),
    '#prefix' => '<div id="custom-print-name">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',

  );
```

Ajax submit callback:

```
/**
 * Ajax callback
 */
function custom_print_ajax_name_callback($form, &$form_state) {

  return $form['name_msg'];
}
```

Everything is working correctly except that when I checked `HTML` of the page, an extra `div` is added in `HTML` of markup after updating `ajax` as shown in below image.

I do not have any idea why is this extra `div` rendering with `markup`.

Thanks in advance.

[image: ajax error]

Comment: What's in `custom_print_ajax_name_callback`?

Comment: Its returning the `return $form['name_msg'];`. I have already added function `custom_print_ajax_name_callback()` in question.

Comment: ok, and how do you know it's AJAX's fault? And not some module theming issue? Also things like that you should inspect using source, firebug shows DOM tree as browser understood it, not as you rendered it to HTML.

Comment: I'd debug `item` type theme function as I don't know about it. I couldn't find any information about it anywhere..

Comment: @Mołot, I am working on fresh `drupal` installation and using default theme and I have checked `html` before `ajax` and after `ajax` and I only get extra 'div' after `ajax` call. I have also checked source of html, as I am using, so it did not show any update html.

Comment: @xurshid29, I had also `debug` and I also did not find anything. I am sure that I am missing something but not idea.

Comment: @Molot, I have checked with `ajax example` module and I found same issue there. So, I think, it issue with `ajax`.

Comment: @JayendraKainthola if you have the same issue with Examples, the very module that was tested by literally hundreds of developers, I can bet dollars to doughnuts that it is *not* issue with AJAX itself, or with implementation (Examples are way too simple and too thoroughly tested), but with some 3rd party, like theme or module you are using. Or it's on the browser side? Well, maybe there is some regression with Core's AJAX, but I have some up-to-date environments and I never noticed it.

Comment: @Mołot, I will also look into this into other environment. I also faced this issue first time, so looking into more into this. I know that this is not a big issue but this can effect the designing.

Comment: Big or no, it is an interesting issue. I simply think you probably blame wrong part of your setup.

Comment: @Mołot, I am simply trying to find a reason why this issue arise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked `ajax.js` in `Drupal` site and I have found that extra `div` is added as `ajax` wraps new content inside an empty div after a successful ajax request.

Comment Mentioned in `ajax.js`:

> We don't know what `response.data` contains: it might be a string of
>   text without HTML, so don't rely on jQuery correctly iterpreting
>   `$(response.data)` as new HTML rather than a CSS selector. Also, if
>   response.data contains top-level text nodes, they get lost with either
>   `$(response.data)` or `$('<div></div>').replaceWith(response.data)`.

Code:

```
var new_content_wrapped = $('<div></div>').html(response.data);
var new_content = new_content_wrapped.contents();
```

Check [this](https://drupal.org/node/736066) also.

Comment: Sorry, Jayendra is wrong. The extra div is added as a container for drupal status messages. Check out includes/ajax.inc line 549 in 7.26: Add the status messages inside the new content's wrapper element, so that on subsequent Ajax requests, it is treated as old content.